# Why does DataGrid size columns differently in a "*" Grid column than a pixel value Grid column?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, auto

I'm working on a simple app that uses a Grid layout with a DataGrid in one of the cells.  Oddly the DataGrid insisted on making the width of its first column much small than its contents, despite having its set to "*".  The issue seems to be coming from the Grid column width being "*" as well: if I change it to a pixel value the DataGrid behaves as expected.

Some other posts suggested setting the `DataGrid` property `HorizontalAlignment` or `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`, or disabling is `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility`, but neither of these worked in this case.

```xml
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Content="Some specific width of content that's reasonably long"/>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  HeadersVisibility="None"
                  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                        Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Cost}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <Label Content="Some specific width of content that's reasonably long"/>

        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  HeadersVisibility="None"
                  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                        Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Cost}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

The above code produces this layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXmpG.jpg.  The `DataGrid` on the left behaves the way I expected, but only because its `GridColumn` width is set to "300".  Why does having a `GridColumn width` of "*" cause the `DataGrid` on the right display differently?

Comment: Try to set `ColumnWidth` for your DataGrids

Comment: Tried setting ColumnWidth for the righthand DataGrid to "*", "Auto" and then "300". None caused any change in the column widths.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to recreate the issue but it seems to behaving fine for me. Is this in another grid that could be affecting the behaviour?